# Can't change role name when I create a role using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm using the following code:

```
message.guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: "test",
        color: 'BLUE'
    },
    reason: 'Bid created',
});
```

to create a new role with discord.js v13, but the role name doesn't change to "test", it remains at "new role".

Comment: Edit: Fixed with: 
        message.guild.roles.create({
            name: 'test',
            color: 'BLUE',
            reason: 'bid created',
          })

Comment: You should mark [`@SuperStormer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71315737/15356407 "Discord.js v13 no longer needs a data object for RoleManager#create")'s answer as the best answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js v13 no longer needs a `data` object for `RoleManager#create` ([changelog](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#rolemanager-create)) :

```js
message.guild.roles.create({
    name: "test",
    color: 'BLUE',
    reason: 'Bid created'
});
```